# Create a text index of files

Tags: python, performance, sorting

This program creates a text index of 3 different files in Python. While this works correctly, I am still a beginner in Python. I used a list of class objects. Can this code be further optimised?

```
class ListNode :
    def __init__(self,w,docslist) :

        self.word = w
        self.docslist = []
        self.docslist.append(docslist)

TextIndex = []

def Search(word,TextIndex) :

    for i in TextIndex :
        if i.word == word :
            return TextIndex.index(i)   
        else :
            continue

    return -1


def Create(docs) :
    for d in docs :
        words = []
        for line in d :
            line = line.split()
            for word in line :
                if word not in words :
                    words.append(word)

            for word in words :

                node = ListNode(word,d.name)

                j = Search(word,TextIndex)

                if j == -1 :
                    TextIndex.append(node)

                else :
                    TextIndex[j].docslist.append(d.name)

def Display() :
    TextIndex.sort(key=lambda x: x.word, reverse=False)
    for i in TextIndex :
        print (i.word,i.docslist)


def main() :

    try :
        with open(r"C:\Users\Anonymous\Documents\words1.txt") as a, open(r"C:\Users\Anonymous\Documents\words2.txt") as b,       open(r"C:\Users\Anonymous\Documents\words3.txt") as c :
        docs = [a,b,c]  
        Create(docs)

        Display()


    except IOError as e :
        print ('Operation Failed: %e' %e.strerror)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Coding style

Please follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python coding style guide.
You have really a LOT of coding style violations,
and it's really hard to read your code this way.

In addition, the variable names are extremely poor,
especially a file handle named `d`,
and a node named `i`,
but an index named `j` is also not great.

#### Choice of data structure

The index is backed by `TextIndex`, a list,
which is inefficient.
The time complexity of a lookup (the `Search` function) is \$O(n)\$.
You can do much better by using a dictionary,
mapping words to nodes.
In fact, the `Search` function would completely disappear,
as you could replace it with a simple condition like `word in TextIndex` to check if something is in the index or not.

#### Working with files

Since all 3 input files are processed exactly the same way,
there's no need to process them all in the same `with` block.
If an error occurs during the processing of one,
the program would exit, so this is fragile, 
and at the same time a very rigid setup.
It would be better to have a helper function in charge of opening and processing a file,
and call this function for each file sequentially.

It's also not great to pass a file handle to another function.
It's a lot clearer to work with a file handle in the `with` block,
read data from it, and then it's ok to pass the read data to another function for further processing.